# Wicket Ajax bad network, server down, what is a good approach?

Tags: ajax, networking, wicket

I'm currently having some network issues, and my `Wicket` application does not react very nicely to the network being sluggish or down. I.e. I see no reaction in my webpage, not even the `AjaxIndicator`.

What would be the approach to tackle shaky networks in Wicket Ajax? And how to present this to the user in such a way that it is not annoyong (like pop-ups etc).

Answer (score 2):

The application is responsible to show Ajax indicator when needed. E.g. you can show it always, or show it only after a delay of N ms [1].
You can also use the browser navigator's online/offline events to tell the user that **her** connection is down [2].

1. https://github.com/apache/isis/blob/587a8bd622c9511389b92102c4308f6dd0dfabab/core/viewer-wicket-ui/src/main/java/org/apache/isis/viewer/wicket/ui/pages/jquery.isis.wicket.viewer.js#L88-L96
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events